# Why is Terminator sending double characters to terminals that aren't selected in broadcast mode?

Tags: command-line, terminator

I'm installing 3 servers in parallel, and am using Terminator with a 3-way split pane to do so.

Any time I go to the context menu in Terminator, and I use the broadcast feature to select "broadcast all", my keypresses will be broadcast to the SSH sessions in all 3 panes, though in the 2 panes I did not select as my "active pane" double the characters will be typed, so, as an example:

```
------------------------
jln@server1: apt upgrade -y

------------------------
jln@server2: aapptt uuppggrraaddee --yy

------------------------
jln@server3: aapptt uuppggrraaddee --yy

------------------------
```

I'm on 19.10 Eoan Ermine.
Used the Terminator package from the official Ubuntu repository.
I have changed no options other than the colours and the showing of the bars at the top of the terminals.

My terminator version:

```
terminator -v
terminator 1.91
```

Answer (score 13):

When I changed the terminator code to

```
del os.environ['DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS']
```

it did not work, and terminator could not run.

Then, soon after `imports`, I set the variable `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` to `''` (null string), and everything is working perfectly fine for me:

```
os.environ['DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS']=''
```

Comment: Yep, I went this route because it seemed less intrusive

❯ `terminator --version`
terminator 2.1.0

❯ `sudo vi \`which terminator\``

Comment: In `/usr/bin/terminator`, add `os.environ['DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS'] = ''` after imports fix the double keystroke issue on Ubuntu. Tested both on 22.04 and 20.04

Comment: thank you , i no longer start terminator  :D with pkill ibus  :P

Answer (score 6):

Change line 142 of the terminator script file to the following.

> sudo nano /usr/share/terminator/terminator

before change (line 142)

```
ibus_running = [p for p in psutil.process_iter() if p.name == 'ibus-daemon' and p.username == username]
```

after change

```
ibus_running = [p for p in psutil.process_iter(['name', 'username']) if p.info['name'] == 'ibus-daemon' and p.info['username'] == username]
```

Comment: For me (terminator v1.91 shipping with ubuntu 20.04) this was line 59. In the repo this is here: https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator/blob/master/terminator#L61. Would you mind opening a pull request?

Comment: Thanks! Nothing worked for me EXCEPT for this. Had this issue on my CentOS machine, so if anyone needs, the path in CentOS is `/usr/bin/terminator` instead of `/usr/share/...`

Answer (score 2):

From [this comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/terminator/+bug/1653496/comments/9) on the [relevant bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/terminator/+bug/1653496) (formatting my own):

> It is the `GTK_IM_MODULE` environment variable (in my system it is
> `GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus`).
>
> If I usent `GTK_IM_MODULE`, terminator works without the bug:
>
> ```
> env --unset=GTK_IM_MODULE terminator
> ```

So unsetting the `GTK_IM_MODULE` environment variable worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Found somewhere and it worked for me...

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/terminator /usr/bin/terminator.SAVE
cat <<TERMINATOR > /tmp/terminator
#!/bin/bash
sh -c "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS='' /usr/share/terminator/terminator"
TERMINATOR
chmod 755 /tmp/terminator
sudo mv /tmp/terminator /usr/bin
```

Comment: A little explanation could improve a lot your answer, giving your source too

Comment: @damadam It's similar to what user3271659 posted but creates a wrapper to terminator instead, It's just much harder to read.

Comment: I've made everything from GUI. I've simply installed alacarte and edited start command for Terminator to be precisely as this one: sh -c "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS='' terminator"

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04. Had to use `sh -c "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS='' /usr/bin/terminator.SAVE` instead.

Answer (score 1):

if you have Ubuntu 20...

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/terminator
```

add after the imports:

```
del os.environ['DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS']
```

Comment: this is the only one that works for me

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was coming from `ibus`.

What I did:

1. `ps ax | grep ibus` and check that `ibus` is running. Then I killed every process with `pkill -f "ibus"`.
2. `sudo apt-get remove ibus` to uninstall ibus from my computer.
3. Go on Terminator and check that characters are no longer duplicated!

I got the info from [Claudio Kuenzler's blog post](https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/862/terminator-terminal-inserting-each-character-twice-double-broadcast-multiple-windows).

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me in Terminator version 2.1.1 on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

```
pkill -9 ibus
```

Answer (score 0):

My small script based on this page information:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/terminator /usr/bin/terminator.orig
sudo vim /usr/bin/terminator
(content of: /usr/bin/terminator)
#!/bin/bash
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS='' /usr/bin/terminator.orig

sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/terminator
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IBUS_NO_SNOOPER_APPS=python3
```

fixed it for me (using `dbus`).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue in Fedora by switching to fcitx.

1. `yum install fcitx`
2. Add to `/etc/environment`

   ```
   GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx
   QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx
   XMODIFIERS=@im=fcitx
   ```
3. Reboot