# Dconf, can read value but not write it (given address is empty)

Tags: gnome, 22.04, dconf, tweak

on ubuntu 20.04, this was working well to tweak my setting via cli:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/text-scaling-factor 0.9
```

however on ubuntu 22.04, I can only read the value

```
$ dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/interface/text-scaling-factor    
0.94999999999999996

$ dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/text-scaling-factor 0.9
error: The given address is empty
```

Any idea how to solve ?
`Gnome tweaks` can modify it, but I want to do it via cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the result of `echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`

If this environment variable is not set then try setting it with:

`export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$UID/bus`

Then try your `dconf write` again.

Comment: it works, variable was indeed empty, thank you !!! would it be wise to put  this in my `.bashrc` ?

Comment: @n0tis I guess that would work, but not sure why it is not already set, on all my PC's/terminals it's set by default. In your case is this just a normal GUI terminal session as a non-root user? Or are you logged in remotely via VNC or SSH or something like that?

Comment: This my my local machine (not connected via ssh/VNC). Very interrestingly, the variable is correctly set by default in  virtual terminal, but not in my usual termnial (accessed via gnome + terminator). This bugs appeared after my update from `20.02` to `22.04`

Comment: I'm on 22.04.2 LTS. I did see something in another post about certain `dbus` packages which should be installed, when I do `apt list --installed |grep ^dbus` it shows `dbus`, `dbus-x11` and `dbus-user-session`. So maybe check you have same packages installed? But I really don't know what all this stuff means/does, I only answered as I has a similar issue as you when writing a backup script which runs as cron - in that case the environment variable was not set and I had to do it in the script.

Comment: thank you, I do have the same package installed, I'll dig a bit more and maybe open another post about this question

Comment: solved, it was terminator config issue, because I did this trick a few weeks ago :
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189243/why-is-terminator-sending-double-characters-to-terminals-that-arent-selected-in
thanks for your help